# Manipulate form element in Drupal 8

Tags: forms, drupal-8

I have a very simpel Drupal 8.0.1 form that are about to become very complicated.

The form is for filling out data to uptain a bank loan.

I have firstname, lastname, street etc etc. and it is working just fine.
Now I need to implement a **co debitor** with firstname, lastname, street etc. etc.

But... The fields for the co debitor **may only be active** if the visitor has checked in a checkbox...

How the heck do I do that with the new Ajax setup in Drupal 8?

I'm a champ @ Drupal 6 and Ahah, but the D8 is a whole new world for me...

Thank you for your time.

Regards, Lars

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if I understand you correctly, do this:

```
$form['co_debitor'] = array(
  '#type' => 'checkbox',
  '#title' => t('Add Co-Debitor'),
  '#default_value' => FALSE
);

$form['co_debitor_firstname'] = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('First name of the co-debitor'),
  '#states' => array(
    // Only show this field when the 'co_debitor' checkbox is checked.
    'visible' => array(
      ':input[name="co_debitor"]' => array('checked' => TRUE),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Now the first name field should be only visible if the checkbox was checked. Let me know if this was what you were looking for.

Comment: Hi Frank, Thank you very much! :-)